# How to change custom menu in your vsix (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I thought that it would be simple. I am working on my custom vsix. I have created menu in code editor menu context. It works fine. But then I wanted to change some text, just

from (vsct file):

```
<Menu guid="guidCodeEditorCmdSet" id="CodeEditorSubMenu" priority="0x0100" type="Menu">
    <Parent guid="guidCodeEditorCmdSet" id="CodeEditorNerdXGroup" />
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>Title</ButtonText>
      <CommandName>Title</CommandName>
    </Strings>
  </Menu>
```

to:

```
<Menu guid="guidCodeEditorCmdSet" id="CodeEditorSubMenu" priority="0x0100" type="Menu">
    <Parent guid="guidCodeEditorCmdSet" id="CodeEditorNerdXGroup" />
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>New menu item</ButtonText>
      <CommandName>Title</CommandName>
    </Strings>
  </Menu>
```

But after cleaning and running the vsix in debug, the menu item text is not changed. It's left as it was. What's more there are some difficulties in creating new menus. Sometimes they are not shown at all. Is there any trick to manage it?

Comment: Close VS, delete `bin` and `obj` folder of your project first. Then, delete the cache folder(the name of your project) under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxx\Extensions\xxx(your current vs account name)`. When you finish them all, restart your project to test again.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. Please give me some time :)

Comment: Hi Adam, any update about this issue? Please check if my answer helps you handle the issue. If it helps, please do not forget to accept it. And if not, please feel free to let us know:)

Comment: Any update about it?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions are these:

**1)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder of your vsix project.

**2)** also,, delete the cache extension under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxx\Extensions\xxx(your current vs account name)\your extension project name`

**When** you finishing them all, restart your project to test again.

Comment: Or please try to run [devenv /SafeMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) to start your VS and then test your extension project.